# How to display spans with border in single line

Tags: html, css

I have DIV with four SPAN's inside, like below and I would like to display them in a single line across the width of the screen using CSS. Each SPAN should have a width equal 25% of screen width and border with 2px width.

```
<div>
    <span>1111111</span>
    <span>2222222</span>
    <span>3333333</span>
    <span>4444444</span>
</div>
```

I try this CSS, but this causing, that last SPAN is displayed below other thre SPAN's.

```
div
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div > span
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}
```

I know about `box-sizing: border-box;` but I have to use CSS2 and box-sizing was introduced in CSS3.

Comment: borders add to total width.
Also check this post
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

I've used it once in a project of mine without problems

Comment: yhea but if he wants the spans to be 25% wide he cant add 2px border

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e7wLu/ In this fiddle it is working.

Comment: @Sakhal Turkaystan yes because you are not using the 100% of the available space.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan Thats not `25%` each tho is it...

Comment: Yes, somehow the width attribute was missing in my fiddle copy...

Comment: [http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box) `box-sizing` should work, but still I would check it in all browser you want to support.

Comment: I know `box-sizing` should work and I try this. But I check this on device and this unfortunely not work. This device is target for my project and everything must work properly on it.

Comment: @user3106462 Check my answer, its got 3 options for you. I could make more options but 3 is more then enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want `100%` width adding a border will disrupt this. `100%` + 2px border on each `span` is over `100%`. This will push one to the next line.

**Possible solution:**

Use outline, pretty much the same as the border but it will not count towards the overall `width`/`height`. Also will overlap each other. Have a play with it but it may do for what you need.

```
div > span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7wLu/1/)

---

**Other possible solution:**

set `margin: -2px` on the span.

```
div > span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 25%;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7wLu/3/)

---

**One more possible solution:**

Use `display: table`.

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
div > span {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7wLu/4/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work in css2 you'll have to be creative.
This is not the prettiest solution, but it will work.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span><span class="sp">1111111</span></span>
    <span><span class="sp">2222222</span></span>
    <span><span class="sp">3333333</span></span>
    <span><span class="sp">4444444</span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div > span
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
span.sp {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

What I did here is added another span. The outer span keeps the 25% sizing while the inner span is on 100% of its container.

Comment: This solution overflows container on the right because you used `width:100%;` on `.sp` see here : http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/PCtM8/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <html>
<head>
<INCLUDE BOOTSTRAP.CSS>
<style>
/*div
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}*/

.blockk
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    /*width: 25%;*/
}
</style>
</head>
<div>
    <div class="span3 blockk" >1111111</div>
    <div class="span3 blockk">2222222</div>
    <div class="span3 blockk" >3333333</div>
    <div class="span3 blockk">4444444</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: but then it wont be 25% there will be a big difference on larger screens

Comment: It is the border treated as inclusive of the dimensions of the elements or not? That's the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use tables by the way.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1111111</td>
    <td>2222222</td>
    <td>3333333</td>
    <td>4444444</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table
{
width: 100%;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
border: 2px solid #000;
cellspacing: 0;
cellpadding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GmJb9/